# Invocation Stack History Overflow

Tags: stack, lisp, stack-overflow, history, invocation

Been playing around with LISP in class. This is admittedly the first LISP code I've written. I can't figure out why this code produces the error `"invocation stack history overflow"` for input values over 2000 to the function `(longest_collatz n)`. Can anyone with more experience in this language help me understand the error?

```
(defun longest_collatz(n)
  (reverse 
   (maxlist
    (loop for x from 1 to n
       collect (list x (length (collatz x)))))))

(defun collatz (n)
  (if (<= n 1)
      '(1)
      (if (= (mod n 2) 0)
          (cons (/ n 2) (collatz (/ n 2)))
          (cons (+ (* n 3) 1) (collatz (+ (* n 3) 1))))))

(defun maxlist (z)
  (if (> (length z) 1)
      (if (< (cadr (elt z 0)) (cadr (elt z 1)))
          (maxlist (cdr z))
          (maxlist (cons (elt z 0) (cddr z))))
      (car z)))
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to for me. `(longest_collatz 3000)` returns `(217 2919)` on `SBCL 1.1.11`. What implementation and version are you using? In general, Common Lisp doesn't guarantee tail-call elimination, so I assume your `maxlist` would be the problem for larger inputs.

Comment: Could you please tell us what your functions are supposed to do? Describe each one. Show input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yout `collatz` function is not tail recursive, so it is unlikely that it is converted to a loop even if you compile your code.

You can rewrite it using an accumulator, so that it is converted to a loop by the compiler:

```
(defun collatz (n &optional acc)
  (unless (plusp n)
    (error "~s(~s): positive argument is required" 'collatz n))
  (if (= n 1)
      (nreverse (cons 1 acc))
      (let ((next (if (evenp n)
                      (ash n -1) ; same as (mod n 2)
                      (1+ (* n 3)))))
        (collatz next (cons next acc)))))
```

(this is a bug-for-bug reimplementation).

Notes:

1. Avoid `elt`; using `first` and `second` instead would be must better.
2. Rewriting `maxlist` using [`reduce`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_reduce.htm) would make it both faster and clearer.

Comment: That's only part of the problem. Can you make the whole thing tail-recursive? And there's not really any reason to return the actual list; just the length would be adequate.

Comment: @ooga: I made `collatz` TR; `maxlist` is already TR, but should be rewritten to use `reduce` for speed and clarity (and to avoid consing).

Comment: I was thinking about the `longest_collatz` function. Does your entire solution work for numbers in the billions? What's the answer for `(longest_collatz 1000000000`)?

Comment: @ooga: `longest_collatz` does not recurse. also, this function does not scale well. however, `(longest_collatz 100000)` takes 11 seconds and returns `(351 77031)`.

Comment: You're right! I read it wrong originally and I though it recursed as well, but it just calls `collatz`. But your returned list is not quite right as it doesn't have the first number and contains 1 twice (although I believe that's what the OP's original code does). And it might run a faster if you just counted the elements instead of returning the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that just returns the length of the collatz list instead of the list itself. It could be more efficient (and is tail recursive).

```
(defun collatz_length2 (n cnt)
  (if (<= n 1)
    cnt
    (if (= (mod n 2) 0)
      (collatz_length2 (/ n 2) (1+ cnt))
      (collatz_length2 (+ (* n 3) 1) (1+ cnt)))))

(defun collatz_length (n) (collatz_length2 n 1))
```